# Is it possible to adjust a csv file using xslt?

Tags: xslt-2.0

if you take this basic comma separated input:
replace,something,incsvfile

Can you use xslt to convert the file i.e. make each value a row for example or replace the word 'replace' with 'replaced'.

Can you point me to a reference link that may help me to learn how to do this please?

The reason for the question is I'm working with an application that can output csv files, and you can apply xslt (2.0) to the output but I dont know how to convert csv into another csv output to post process it and I cannot work out how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: XSLT 2 and later, instead of starting processing with an XML input, can start processing with a named template and the `unparsed-text` function can read in a text file (e.g. `<xsl:template name="main"><xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('sample.csv'), '&#10;')">...</xsl:for-each></xsl:template>`)

Comment: Actually, above @MartinHonnen gives you the correct answer. I just wanted to add that you need to create a dummy.xml and set it as an input.

Comment: @VasylKrupa, XSLT 2 or 3 processors usually have an option and/or API to start processing with a named template (e.g. `-it:main` for Saxon) so there is no need to have a dummy XML input document.